# how to resolve system.nullreference exception when calling web application from console application

Tags: c#

I have added dll reference of my web application inside console application.
I am trying to call web application functions by creating object of web app inside console app.
But the web application controls all are null, throwing null reference exception.

Can anyone help resolving this issue?

Here is my sample code
I am using RadControls Web Application. there is one Radhtmlchart control.

### webapp.aspx

```
<telerik:Radhtmlchart id=chart1 runat="server"/>
```

### webapp.aspx.cs

I am binding control to datasource.

```
public void Loadchart()
{
chart1.datasource= getdata();
chart1.databind
}
```

### consoleapp

```
using webapp;

webapp obj= new webapp();
obj.Loadchart();
```

while running the console app, I am getting error on Chart1.;object reference not set to instance of object.

Comment: No, we can't. Unless you provide some code.

Comment: Don't you have code to show? There's no way you can get an error without code. Otherwise the program would be like run and close immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you should change your approach a little because a console application does not have a GUI. Therefore the web application controls would not be expected to exist.

Using a model/view architecture, move all of your data specific code to a "Model", where "Model" is one or more classes that store and manipulate the data, and have your "View", that is GUI controls, instantiate and use your "Model" classes. Then instantiate only your "Model" classes within your console app.

If you have GUI specific string manipulation code - code that readies strings for the GUI, you should move that into a separate class as well, so that you can call it from both the console and web app.